# Remove break lines in wrapped cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, linebreaks

I want to get rid of unnecessary break lines from cells and leave the ones I need to separate wrapped text. I'm outta ideas how to distinct them from each other and remove some of them which are useless like in the example below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question so, that the OP searches a solution for describing these line breaks, he wants to eliminate. I assume OP knows how to solve the task programmatically and I recommend doing the removal with a VBA macro. (The search criterias are pseudo-like VBA.)

The first line break is always at the first position of the string. So the search criteria is something like `FIND(CHAR(10); <StringValue>) == 1`.

The other line breaks are always at the last position of the string. So the search criteria is something like `IF(FIND(CHAR(10); <StringValue>) == LENGTH(<StringValue>)`.

The third possible line break is not shown in the examples, it would be a blank line between two texts. Obviously this are two consecutive `CHAR(10)` and can be removed with a simple "search and replace".

Note that the search criterias have to be used in a loop to get multiple occurrences.